# How to get next value of enum

Tags: c++, enums

I have the following problem:

```
    enum Language { English, French, German, Italian, Spanish };

    int main() {

    Language tongue = German;
    tongue = static_cast<Language>(tongue + 1);

      cout << tongue;                  

}
```

//it returns 3.....but i want to get the language name on index 3.....

Comment: If you're using indices, why not `std::array` or `std::vector`? If you want your indices to be meaningful (not just consecutive integers), then `std::map` is a good candidate.

Comment: can you plz codify it for me as im not as familiar with C++ syntax

Comment: I just want to get next enum value if i provide previous one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that an explicit look up table works best, for both converting from enum to text and text to enum:

```
enum Language_Enum
{
    LANGUAGE_FIRST = 0,
    LANGUAGE_GERMAN = LANGUAGE_FIRST,
    LANGUAGE_ENGLISH,
    LANGUAGE_HOPI,
    LANGUAGE_WELSH,
    LANGUAGE_TEXAN,
    LANGUAGE_DUTCH,
    LANGUAGE_LAST
};

struct Language_Entry
{
    Language_Enum   id;
    const char *    text;
};

const Language Entry  language_table[] =
{
    {LANGUAGE_GERMAN, "German"},
    {LANGUAGE_HOPI, "Hopi"},
    {LANGUAGE_DUTCH, "Dutch"},
    // ...
};
const unsigned int language_table_size =
    sizeof(language_table) / sizeof(language_table[0]);
```

Specifying the `enum` along with the text, allows for the enum order to change with minimal effect to the search engine.

The `LANGUAGE_FIRST` and `LANGUAGE_LAST` identifiers allow for iteration of the enum:

```
Language_Enum l;
for (l = LANGUAGE_FIRST; l < LANGUAGE_LAST; ++l)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to create an array of strings which matches your enum e.g.

```
std::string[] LangTxt = { "English", "French", "German", "Italian", "Spanish" };
```

then you can reference them as follows:

```
cout << LangTxt[tongue];
```

Be careful to keep the definitions together though so they are updated side by side.

Comment: I always wonder why is that the first post always gets up-vote, though subsequent ones are almost similar!

Comment: @tuxuday: Because of exactly that?

Answer (score 2):

It is not so simple to print the enum name for a given enum value in C++. Instead, you can use a map or string array to hold the values, which do allow you to get both the index and the string value.

Comment: is it possible to get index value by providing enum name or vice versa

Comment: @GhazanfarAli, You can use `std::distance` with iterators or addresses to do that, but in that case it would be easier to loop through like a normal array, using an index sentinel.

Comment: what will be output for this line    tongue = static_cast<Language>(1);   cout<<tongue;

Answer (score 0):

Best Way to use enum is first give initial value to your enum.
enum TestEnum
{
    Zero=0,
    One,
    Two
}
Even you wont specify anything the default starting index is zero.
To get the value at a particular index simple do that

```
TestEnum(index);
```

Comment: But all you can output is still the index using an enum.